# How to load the second tab in a UITabBarcontroller on a button click..??

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a initial `UIViewController`. I have two buttons on the `UIViewController`, one being `Tutorial` and the other being `Start`.

When I click on `Tutorial` then I will be navigating to a `UITabBarController` where `Tutorial` is the default(first) tab. I have no problem with this. I have done by holding and right clicking and dragging to `UITabBarController` and selecting modal.

But when I click the `Start` button I will have to navigate to the second tab on the `UITabBarController`. How can this be done???

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `UITabBarController.selectedIndex` property to the index of the tab you want to use.

Comment: UITabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
When I do this I will get an error saying that Property 'selectedIndex' not found on object type 'UITabBarController'

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you should set that property on *your* UITabBarController; i.e., the IBOutlet you get from creating it.

Comment: I am new to iOS development could you please tell me how to do that
I have a mytabBarcontroller on the story board I have created .h and .m files subclassed UItabBarController I have a global variable which will set to 1 when I click on the button. Now in viewDidLoad of tabBarController i am checking for the globalvariable and setting the index of the tab to be selected.
just to let you know I have written the NSLog to display the value of the globalvariable in viewDidLoad of mytabBarController.m class but that is not being displayed on console. So how do i link h and m files

Comment: That myTabBarController is the one you want - set .selectedIndex on that to 1 (doing it in viewDidLoad should be OK; in that case you'd be setting self.selectedIndex = 1).